# Kato's explicit reciprocity law paper

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-hodge-theory, paper-request

Does anyone have a copy of Kato's article *Generalized explicit reciprocity laws* in Advanced Studies in Contemp. Math which is used heavily in his paper constructing his eponymous Euler system? I used to be able to find a PDF on Google, but it seems to have vanished.

Comment: You can find it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220531053712/http://www.math.columbia.edu/~phlee/F16-Kato/GER.pdf)

Comment: thank you so much!